# Как запретить nginx кешировать директорию и все файлы в ней?

Tags: nginx, php7, кэширование

```
http {
fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=asp:10m max_size=256m inactive=7d;
...
}

server {
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 304 7d;
fastcgi_cache_key "$request_method|$http_if_modified_since|$http_if_none_match|$host|$request_uri";

...

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$){
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_cache asp;
}
    ...
```

Имеется такой конфиг nginx. Web-сервер настроен как nginx + php7.0-fpm. 
Настроил кэширование выдачи выполнения php файлов (не силен в определениях, поправьте). 
Мне нужно отключить кеширование в директории и все файлы в ней, к примеру, admin. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#запрет кеширование директории administrator
server{
...
    location ~* ^/administrator/ {
    fastcgi_pass_header    Set-Cookie;
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$){
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;

    }
}
```